# Flutter AnimatedList: itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < _itemsCount is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm managing items in an `AnimatedList` widget like that:

```dart
void _findAndAnimateDifferences(
  List<Reservation> newReservations, {
  List<Reservation> oldReservations = const [],
}) {
  _findIndexDifferences(newReservations, oldReservations).forEach((index) {
    widget.listKey.currentState?.insertItem(index);
  });
  _findIndexDifferences(oldReservations, newReservations).forEach((index) {
    final reservation = oldReservations[index];
    widget.listKey.currentState?.removeItem(
      index,
      ...
    );
  });
}

List<int> _findIndexDifferences(
  List<Reservation> a, [
  List<Reservation> b = const [],
]) {
  final difference = a.toSet().difference(b.toSet());
  return difference
      .map<int>((reservation) => a.indexOf(reservation))
      .toList();
}
```

`_findIndexDifferences` works ok, I tested that.

For the most part it works fine: adding elements is working and deleting one by one is ok too. When it comes to deleting more than one element at once it fails though, with an error:

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/animated_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 12: 'itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < _itemsCount': is not true.)
```

What causes the problem?

Legend:

- `widget.listError` is a `GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>` instance

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting elements you have to reverse differences list, here's why:

```dart
_findIndexDifferences(oldReservations, newReservations)
        // The differences list has to be reversed because .removeItem
        // deletes given index immediately, thus shifting indexes if
        // we're deleting from 0 to length.
        //
        // Eg. The list have 8 elements. 2 indexes are meant for deletion
        // say, 2, and 7. If we go through the list in the ascending
        // order we'll be shifting positions for elements further elements,
        // like that:
        //        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        // DEL 2:        ^
        // Indexes shifting! We deleted the second one, but to avoid an
        // empty space in a resulting list, further indexes drops down by 1,
        // so 3 falls to 2, 4 falls to 3, ..., and 7 falls to 6:
        //        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        // Now, we still have a 7 to delete. If we try that, we'll have an
        // error, since there's no 7th index anymore:
        // DEL 7: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        //                             ^ // itemIndex < _itemsCount is not true!
        //
        // Going in the descending order mitigates index shifting, since we
        // are sure that shifting doesn't happen in the part of a list we're
        // heading to.
        .reversed
        .forEach((index) {
      final reservation = oldReservations[index];
      widget.listKey.currentState?.removeItem(
        index,
...
```

Adding was working because it doesn't depend on indexes, and deleting one by one was working because it couldn't generate a shifting issue for itself.

[AnimatedListState.removeItem](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedListState/removeItem.html) docs for reference.